# Android Kotlin covert object initialisation to lambda with override methods

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

How can I covert this method to lambda and still have override methods because it shows warning that I should convert this part `object : OnSuccessListener<GoogleSignInAccount>` to lambda

Method:

```
task.addOnSuccessListener( object : OnSuccessListener<GoogleSignInAccount>{
        override fun onSuccess(p0: GoogleSignInAccount?) {

        }

    })
```

After converting I don't have override method `onSuccess`

```
task.addOnSuccessListener{ googleSignInAccount ->

    }
```

Comment: after lambda conversion,
 { googleSignInAccount ->
         // this is your onSuccess method
    }

Comment: All lambdas in Kotlin and Java are implementations of interfaces with a single abstract method which override this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it right! The code you write after -> is what will be executed when onSuccess is called.

```
task.addOnSuccessListener { googleSignInAccount ->
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not have lambda converted method and have overriden method because lambda method(java 8) implicitly call overriden method and this is the best part about kotlin that you can reduce your code

happy coding!